# How to rename the xml root element in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sqlxml

I have a xml variable like this:

```
<root a1="3794" a2="7">
  <price p1="8805" p2="5" p3="259.9000" />
  <price p1="8578" p2="5" p3="100.0000" />
</root>
```

I want to rename the `root` to `discount`, output should be:

```
<discount a1="3794" a2="7">
  <price p1="8805" p2="5" p3="259.9000" />
  <price p1="8578" p2="5" p3="100.0000" />
</discount>
```

Does anybody have a better solution for this while keeping the variable as a xml?

Thanks

Comment: What's the specific database engine?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really renaming the element. It is creating a new xml with a new root element name.

```
declare @X xml = 
'<root a1="3794" a2="7">
  <price p1="8805" p2="5" p3="259.9000" />
  <price p1="8578" p2="5" p3="100.0000" />
</root>';

select @X.query('element discount {root/@*, /root/*}');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

```
select cast(replace(cast(myXmlCol as varchar(max)), 'root', 'discount') as xml)
from my_table
```